# How to notify users from within a module

Tags: 7

I'm building a custom module for a project and would like to display a notification/warning to the user once something happens. For instance, my module would trigger a Mailchimp action. Once I get the Ok from Mailchimp, I'd like to show a message to user, something like using Devel's `dvm` or `dpm` function.

How can I accomplish this (preferably without additional modules)?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I could use Devel, but I'd rather disable it in production env.

Comment: Piece of cake if adding 1 module would be acceptable anyway (instead of re-inventing the wheel?), which would enable a zillion of possible scenarios you could cover with it. Let me know if you ever want to consider *changing your mind*. PS: maybe you should enhance your question to explain why you don't want additional modules? Afraid of *modulitis* (= way too much modules already)?

Comment: I want to know about the module @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: @Umair : merci for informing me, but unless the question is adapted, I think I'm not "allowed" (hm, hm) to add my answer. BTW: I'm about to answer your previous (followup) question from some days ago (I think I can get it to work, but need to do some extra checking first ...).

Comment: This sounds good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`drupal_set_message()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x) is what you're looking for.

Sample usage:

```
drupal_set_message('Mailchimp action is successfully executed.');
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work... I didn't see the notification on the backend theme nor on the frontend. I've literally done as your example above.

Comment: Are you sure that the related part of the code is really executed? And please check if in your template `page.tpl.php` that the messages are printed somewhere like: `<?php print $messages; ?>`